# "sudo bash -s --" without changing $HOME?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, sudo, environment-variables

I'd like to run a trusted script from the internet with the `sudo` command like so:

```bash
sudo curl https://example.org/my-trusted-example.script.sh | sudo bash -s --
```

The script is using the `$HOME` variable. On Debian this variable will resolve to `/root` instead of `/home/user`.

How can let it use the home user directory instead of the root user directory?

Comment: If the script is using `$HOME`, then why would it need to be run with `sudo`. This sounds like a very broken design, are you _sure_ you want to trust it?

Comment: @terdon It's my script and I have over-thought my design decision. I rather put `sudo` in my script whenever I need it to not mess up ownerships of any files.

Comment: Well, your call, but I would post a question about the script. There are many ways around that, and I bet some of the folks here would be able to suggest important improvements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask `sudo` to [preserve specified environment variables](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudo.man/#preserve-env=list):

```
% sudo printenv HOME
/root
% sudo --preserve-env=HOME printenv HOME
/home/muru
```

You can also set `HOME` yourself:

```
curl https://example.org/my-trusted-example.script.sh | sudo HOME="$HOME" bash -s --
curl https://example.org/my-trusted-example.script.sh | sudo env HOME="$HOME" bash -s --
```

---

But since it is running the script as root, you will likely create mess up ownership of files in your home directory.

---

(`curl` shouldn't be needing `sudo`.)

Comment: Also note that the `-s --` are redundant here. They would make sense if you wanted to pass arguments to the script as in `curl ... | ... bash -s -- -i input -o output`.